# MessageHeader lost on second call?

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, header

I have 2 projects, project 1 have a reference to project 2.

**Project 1** is using a simple service reference with a proxy class to connect to service. To be able to send username/password in header the following code is used on this proxy class :

```
public static void Connect()
{
    _Myclient = new MyService.MyIntegrationClient();

    _Scope = new OperationContextScope(_Myclient.InnerChannel);

    IntegrationHeader ih = new IntegrationHeader
    {
        UserName = Properties.Settings.Default.MyUserLogin,
        Password = Properties.Settings.Default.MyUserPassword
    };

    MessageHeader untyped = MessageHeader.CreateHeader("SecurityToken", "ns", ih);
    OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(untyped);
}
```

So far so good, no problem to run and the usernamen/password can be read on service.

**Project 2** are using channelFactory instead to connect to the same service. The code for creating the channel and adding messageheader looks like this :

```
public static IMyIntegration GetMyFactory(string userName, string password)
{
    IMyIntegration client;
    OperationContextScope operationContextScope;
    IntegrationHeader integrationHeader;
    ConfigurationChannelFactory<IMyIntegration> factory;
    MessageHeader messageHeader;

    integrationHeader = new IntegrationHeader { UserName = userName, Password = password };
    messageHeader = MessageHeader.CreateHeader("SecurityToken", "ns", integrationHeader);
    factory = new ConfigurationChannelFactory<IMyIntegration>("BasicHttpBinding_IMyIntegration", ConfigHelper.MyConfiguration, null);
    client = factory.CreateChannel();
    operationContextScope = new OperationContextScope((IClientChannel)client);

    if (OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Count < 1)
        OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(messageHeader);

        return client;
    }
```

This is how the IntegrationHeader looks like :

```
[DataContract()]
public class IntegrationHeader
{
    [DataMember]
    public string UserName;
    [DataMember]
    public string Password;
}
```

**Project 1** will first run a method in **project 2** that connects(using above code) to a service Method at the service. After this is done **project 1** will also make a connection to the same service but with the code that is first in this post.

So far so good, no problem.

**Problem**
The two service methods is then triggered again(a second time) but this time the above code is not needed because it was already done on the prev loop, so this time we do the service method request directly without creating any proxy classes or channelFactories.

The result is that the header on the sent message is missing this second time on the service?

If I remove the service call made by **project 1** (the one with the proxy) there will be no problems?

**Edit 1 :**

If I only run the service calls that **Project 1** does then it will work just fine, and if I only run the Service Calls that **Project 2** does it will also work fine. The problem is when doing Project 2 call, Project 1 call and then back to Project 2 call again.

If I run it the other way around, **Project 1**, **Project 2** then **Project 1** again it will also fail on the same problem (third Project 1 call)?

**Edit 2 :**

I am using the OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders in both cases and it is only set the at the first call for each project, maybe thay are using the same context?

Comment: Maybe OperationContextScope is being recycling by GC becuase when GetMyFactory ends it's out of scope and nobody is referencing it. This could explain why a inmediate call works but after 1 minute (or right after GC colected out of scope references) fails.

Comment: Hi, you might be right, I have update my post and explained it a bit better. If the OperationContextScope is the problem, how should I handle this? I is decleared like this : private  static OperationContextScope _Scope; so it should not be disposed?

Comment: I do not think that the problem is in GetMyFactory, the problem is probably in the Connect method in project 1.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the OperationContextScope is being disposed by the time your second call is made (after the one minute pause).

This will result in OperationContext.Current returning the previous instance of the operation context before the scope was created, which does not contain any headers.

The way to fix this would be to move the OpertationContextScope initialization out of the factory method:

```
var client = GetMyFactory("username", "password);
using (operationContextScope = new OperationContextScope((IClientChannel)client))
{
    OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(messageHeader);
    client.DoSomething()
    ....
}
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontextscope%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> When an OperationContextScope is created, the current OperationContext
>   is stored and the new OperationContext becomes the one returned by the
>   Current property. When the OperationContextScope is disposed, the
>   original OperationContext is restored.

Comment: I have runned some more tests as you can see in my Edit post. Even if there is no dealy there will be missing headers. So if I run Project1, Project2 and then Project1 again the heder will be missing from Project1 call. And if instead run Project2, Project1 and then Project 1 again the same problem is shown? First time a project service call is runned it will be instanciated. So my guess is that the second service call will clear the settings set by the first service call. But how this is possible when they is in different projects and the channel is created in diffrent way, i dont understand.

Comment: I am using the OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders in both cases, maybe thay are infact using the same context and this is why it fails the third time?

Comment: I'm not sure about that, but I think you need to be creating a new scope and setting headers around each client call, rather than once when you create the client.

Comment: Im sure that it is not needed if I just use one of the solution(Project 1(proxy) or Project 2(channel factory)). When when using thay both it seems like thay interference with each other? If I close the connection between each call and creates a new connect for each call everything will work just fine. So in someway thay are interfarens with each other

Comment: In that case how you are running the projects is the problem - are they being hosted in their own processes?

Comment: Project 2 is a built as an extension that is loaded while Project 1 is loaded. There is nothing more to it.

Comment: Not sure I understand "built as an extension that is loaded". Are they running in their own host processes?